# Why is `Functor ((->) r)` not shown on the Functor documentation

Tags: haskell, functor

In the source code, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-801, ((->) r) is defined as an instance of Functor, but I can't find the corresponding entry on its documentation page, https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Functor.html.

Why is this? Is this intentional or what?

Comment: It's there - I guess it looks a bit funny (`Functor ((->) LiftedRep LiftedRep r)`)

Comment: The funny rendering seems to have been fixed recently too. https://github.com/haskell/haddock/issues/713